# no-index attribute when crawling Oracle portal from SharePoint

Tags: search, 2007, oracle

We are trying to crawl an Oracle Portal from SharePoint 2007.

We are getting a no-index attribute error in the crawl log file.

Does anyone know why we are getting this error? Could it be a setting on the Oracle side blocking the crawler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious place to start troubleshooting would be on the Oracle side I would think. Does the crawl log give you a specific url that you can browse to with a browser?

If so, check the html source of the page and see if there is a robots meta tag similar to the following

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Secondly, check to see if there is a robots.txt file at the root of the Oracle site which may also be instructing the crawler to keep out.

Comment: Thanks, it turned out that it was an authentication problem.